# Mac app installation: How to get the destination disk when installing an app?

Tags: macos, installation

I'm now confused by the Mac app installation steps after packaging my app to .pkg. When the mac contains more than one disk, and when installing the app, after I change the destination disk to another one, like '/Volumes/Disk2', I need to know the disk name after the installation. But I can not find a way to get it.

I am using [Iceberg](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Iceberg.html) to package the app. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, I got the solution to this question: define my own installer plugin, use cocoa api

> tVol = [[[self section] state] targetVolumePath];

to get the Volume path. [reference from mactech](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.25/25.06/InstallerPlugins/index.html)